# Ansible pass json in varibale in ansible-playbook --extra-vars=

Tags: json, ansible

i try to pass JSON structure into ansible-playbook without success:
this is the command I try to pass

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars='[{\"${foo1}\": \"somevalue1\", \"${foo2}\": \"somevalue2\"}, {\"${zoo1}\": \"somevalue111\", \"${zoo2}\": \"somevalue222\"}]' test.yml
```

getting error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected ',' or '}', but got '{'
```

or this :

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars='[{"${foo1}":"somevalue1","${foo2}":"somevalue2"},{"${zoo1}":"somevalue111","${zoo2}":"somevalue222"}]' test.yml
```

Getting no output

The ideal way is passing the JSON into variable like this so i could iterate the json array in ansible :

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars="AAA='[{\"${foo1}\": \"somevalue1\", \"${foo2}\": \"somevalue2\"}, {\"${zoo1}\": \"somevalue111\", \"${zoo2}\": \"somevalue222\"}]'" test.yml
```

with this playbook :

```
---
-
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  name: test
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ AAA }}"
```

The output is :

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - ? ''
    : somevalue2
  - ? ''
    : somevalue222
```

In short, what is the best way to pass JSON structure into ansible without using the file?

Comment: i think the `ansible-playbook` command accepts a `JSONObject` rather than a `JSONArray`, i've passed json objects before, however, they were in a key-value format only, can you see if that works? I also know that it's very sensitive about using single or double quotes on the object

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#json-string-format

Answer (score 5):

I don't follow why you're escaping the `"` inside of a `'` string, but you will want to switch away from the `KEY=VALUE` syntax because in that form, ansible splits on whitespace -- by leading with the `{` it informs ansible that the --extrav-vars is in fact JSON and stops using the key-value parser

```sh
ansible -e '{"AAA": [{"hello":{"world": true}}, {"array":{"yup":"forsure"}}]}' -m debug -a var=AAA localhost
```

produces

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "AAA": [
        {
            "hello": {
                "world": true
            }
        },
        {
            "array": {
                "yup": "forsure"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```